# Logitech extreme 3d pro joystick

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, logitech, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This joystick isn't driving the diff_drive_controller right. Forward is good, reverse is good, steering in reverse is good, but steering forward is backwards. When I want to go left, robot goes right! Is the best solution for this to remap the joystick output? I see there's a node that can change input values into others, for keypad or joystick. joystick_remapper. I see good examples and description of button remapping but none of axis remapping. Or would this behavior be corrected with different values in the covariance matrix in the parameters for diff_drive? My robot is the RosJet (or very like it.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280779/logitech-extreme-3d-pro-joystick/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This corrected itself. I was driving the unit backwards and didn't know it. When I changed from the small (test) robot to the large one, the motor connections happened to be reversed, so it went correctly. The steering in reverse with joystick is a little strange, the caster portion of robot moves the direction of the joystick but the base motion is the other way as you drive. This would be just a matter of choice, I suppose, that the creators of diff_drive decided. It isn't a problem now, since I expect to spend little time driving in reverse.

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0